# Problem running RMI server

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to run a RMI server application. I issue the following command:
`java exemploRMI.Server`

and I got the following error:

```
Problemas no Servidor:
RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: exemploRMI.OlaRemoto
```

How to correct this error?

Problemas no Serivord means "Problems in the server" in Portuguese.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more detail.  Sounds like a classpath issue.  Is there a folder exemploRMI where you are running the java command?  Is this just a class file that you are trying to run?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I have a folder called exemploRMI and my Server.class is in there. How should I correct this issue?

Comment: have you started RMI registry and used rmic to generate stubs.

Comment: Yes I started the rmiregistry and have the stubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -classpath . exemploRMI.Server
```

It seems like a classpath issue. Basically, java needs to know where to look for the name of the class you are calling.  It doesn't auto assume that the current directory is part of your classpath.  [Classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Comment: I got the follwing error when trying to do that: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"

Comment: Now I solved the problem thanks to your answer. I tried to run with: "java -classpath . exemploRMI.Server" and it worked!

Comment: Haha, yeah I just realized I made that mistake and edited my answer!

Comment: Why did you deleted your answer?